# Как в postman написать GET запрос со знаком =

Tags: postman

нужна ваша помощь.
Нужно написать GET запрос по который будет выдавать только те поля которые содержат символ "="
По типу: https://abc.operator = "="
Пробовал задать через ASCII, тоже не сработало
https://abc.operator = %3D

Comment: А зачем? И приведите нормальный пример, а то в вашем нет GET-параметров и вообще непонятно что должно происходить

Comment: поищите видео в ютубе видео по знаку равно и смотрите какой у них на это юрл

Comment: и покажите что конкретно Вы отправляете через постман